# How to represent infinite date in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

Just a simple question.  I want to pass some string to CDate that represents infinite date.

Are there any ways to do like this? :

```
date = CDate("INFINITE FUTURE")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no infinite date in VBScript. There are upper and lower limits on what a Date can be.

However you could use **Dec 31 9999** to represent infinity. For all practical purposes it is so large it may as well be infinity.

```
date = CDate("Dec 31 9999")
```